# Are there any ready-to-use VMs having Oracle Database and EM Cloud Control?

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, virtualbox, oracle12c, oracle-enterprise-manager

The thing is that I am studying Oracle database administration, and I want to test everything out on a VM where it has Oracle Database 12c edition, along with Enterprise Manager Cloud Control.

Are there any VMs that are ready to be used after deployment having those products? It doesn't matter if it have linux OS or windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to study database _administration_, you'd be well advised to forgo a pre-built vm and build your own from scratch.  You will learn much more that way.  Necessary knowledge for a DBA is not confined to the database itself.  You also need to have some knowledge of networking and OS admin.  Building your own VM from scratch will be a valuable learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

See [Pre-Built Developer VMs (for Oracle VM VirtualBox)](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html). Yes, I know - you want *Enterprise Manager Cloud Control* (EMCO) but I wouldn't know whether any of those has it or not.

I'm not a DBA so I have no idea what it actually is, but - if it can be downloaded and installed separately (why not? Most, if not all Oracle software is free to download and use for educational purposes), perhaps you could install one of those virtual machines and - additionally - install EMCO.